# How to convert incoming String request to JSON Request in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping

I want to send a string which represents a JSON, in a request to a Springboot application. I know that if we send JSON request, and create equivalent Object model of that JSON request, then Springboot will automatically map incoming JSON request to Java Object.

I can convert String to JSON and then to its object model using Jackson once my springboot application receives string request, but I dont want to do in that way, I need to have a mapping like JSON to object conversion by default Springboot mapping.

Need help to achieve the same.

Below is my controller :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/eventListener/v5",
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String receiveEventForV5(@RequestBody EventV5 event){
        logger.info(" FaultEvent Details : " + event);
        eventValidationService.validateEvent(VES5_VERSION,event);
        return "FaultEvent received" + event;
    }
```

And request string is :

"event": {

```
"commonEventHeader": {
  "version": 2.0,
  "eventName": "abc",
  "domain": "fault1",
  "eventId": "001-000000000001",
  "eventType": "adadas",
  "nfcNamingCode": "ijk",
  "nfNamingCode": "add",
  "sourceId": "source_entity_id_123abc",
  "sourceName": "source_entity_name_oam",
  "reportingEntityId": "reporting_entity_id_123abc",
  "reportingEntityName": "reporting_entity_name_oam",
  "priority": "High",
  "startEpochMicrosec": 1527089079615,
  "lastEpochMicrosec": 1527089079615,
  "sequence": 0
},
```

It still shows unsupported data type.

Comment: _then Springboot will automatically map incoming JSON request to Java Object_ and _I need to have a mapping like JSON to object conversion by default Springboot mapping._ ? Let me clarify, you need a Json String to Java Object conversion and it should be done automatically, and spring-boot already provides that. So, what is the problem, why not use `consumes="MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE"` and `@RequestBody` ?

Comment: I have updated my query after your suggestion, still its not working.,

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

You can use HandlerMethodArgumentResolver to conver string body to object using ObjectMapper in spring mvc.

For example how to use  HandlerMethodArgumentResolver: 
 https://github.com/jinternals/custom-argument-resolvers-spring-controller

Solution 2 :

Try custom http message converters using AbstractHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: I am new to Spring boot, can you please help with any example

Comment: Check git link in solution 1